# If category only contains one product then link user directly to the product

Tags: magento-1.7, category-products

Our category page child category links are generated using the code below. However, some categories only contain one product. If the category contains only one product is there a way to link directly to that product page rather than the category product listing page?

For example; the 'widgets' category contains only 1 product 'widget'. So rather than the code below generating a link to 'mywebsite.com/main-category/widgets.html' the link would go directly to 'mywebsite.com/widget-product.html

```
<?php 
                //If there are sub categories
                $categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
                $categoriescount = $this->getCurrentChildCategories()->count();
                if ($categoriescount > 0): 
                ?>
                <div class="container_12">  
                    <?php 
                    //Loop through categories
                    foreach ($categories as $category):
                    ?>
                    <div class="grid_3 alpha special-spacing" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                        <div>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="cat-link"><?php echo $category->getName()?></a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="cat-image">
                        <?php 
                        // If there is a thumbnail set for the category - Display it
                        if($imgUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getImage()):?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."media/catalog/category/".$imgUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <?php else:?>
                <p>No Sub Categories</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<?php 
            //If there are sub categories
            $categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
            $categoriescount = $this->getCurrentChildCategories()->count();
            if ($categoriescount > 0):  ?>
            <div class="container_12">  
            <?php 
                //Loop through categories
                foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                <div class="grid_3 alpha special-spacing" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div>
                    <?php //get category products
                        $categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection();
                       if(count($categoryProducts) > 1):?>
                         <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="cat-link"><?php echo $category->getName()?></a>
                      <?php else:?>
                      <?php $product = $categoryProducts->getFirstItem();?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()" class="cat-link"><?php echo $product->getName()?></a>
                      <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="cat-image">
                    <?php 
                    // If there is a thumbnail set for the category - Display it
                    if($imgUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getImage()):?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."media/catalog/category/".$imgUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <?php else:?>
            <p>No Sub Categories</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

We are utilising this method from `class Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`

```
  /**
   * Get category products collection
   *
   * @return Varien_Data_Collection_Db
   */
  public function getProductCollection()
  {
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
          ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
          ->addCategoryFilter($this);
      return $collection;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Adarsh - can I ask please is the code above correct? I've added it to the phtml file but it looks as though the php tags don't open/close correctly.

Comment: I've managed to get it working Adarash but there is no link text - is there anyway I can call the parent category name as the link text rather than the product name?

Comment: Yea you can, just replace <?php echo $product->getName()?> with any name you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coding you can add apache/nginx 301 redirects to url. Let me know if you need syntax.

Comment: Yesha, how does that work? I am looking for some code that says 'if category contains 1 product then product url else category url.

Comment: I haven't updated code. I had same scenario but I'm using 301 nginx redirects which redirecting category page url to product page url.

Comment: We have 1000's of categories however and I am not sure exactly which categories only contain one product.